# When i Add Fragments Dynamically it showing error

Tags: java, android, fragment

Whenever i add fragments dynamically it showing error in Main Activity it does not resolve FragmentManger class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    FirstFragment ff= new FirstFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,ff);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

thanks For help in Advance..

Comment: use getSupportFragmentManager() and Fragment of v4 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mix with fragment and v4.fragment

Answer (score 2):

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, MyFragment);  
    transaction.show(mapFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```